# What is a good reference for the mechanical properties of materials at cryogenic temperatures?

Tags: temperature, material-science

I want to research various the properties of various materials, namely tensile strength at cryogenic temperatures (~20K). I was wondering if a freely available database of material properties exists.

Comment: I don't know, but if you come up with a good one, please put it on this question as well: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14649/what-widely-recognized-organizations-set-standards-used-by-physics

Answer (score 2):

I know you probably tried googling this yourself, but is http://cryogenics.nist.gov/MPropsMAY/material%20properties.htm helpful? It is the first result for me from the query "cryogenic properties database."

EDIT: Also: http://cryogenics.nist.gov/Papers/Cryo_Materials.pdf

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the response. I came across the second link before but not the first. The first is great but I'm hoping there might be something more extensive/comprehensive.