# What is the difference between physical dimensions and physical quantities?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

What is the difference between [physical dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) and [physical quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_quantity) if the dimension of mass is also mass?

Comment: [Related Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/meaning-of-dimension-in-dimensional-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the unit of work done and the torque acting on the body. The unit of work is Joules ($J$ or $Nm$), whereas that of torque is ($Nm$). Comparing dimension wise, they both have the same; but they are not the same physical quantity. Torque is the rotational analogue of force . While the work done on a body is the dot product of the translation force and the position vector.

Comment: Pretty sure work and torque are $Nm$, not $N/m$.

Comment: @noah Oops!! I have edited it. Could you please remove your downvote?